# Three.js merging mesh/geometry objects

Tags: performance, three.js

I'm creating a three.js app which consists of floor (which is composed of different tiles) and shelving units (more than 5000...). I'm having some performance issues and low FPS (lower then 20), and I think it is because I'm creating a separate mesh for every tile and shelving unit. I know that I can leverage geometry/mesh merging in order to improve performance. This is the code for rendering the floor and shelving units (cells):

```
// add ground tiles
const tileGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(
  1,
  1,
  1
);
const edgeGeometry = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(tileGeometry);
const edges = new THREE.LineSegments(edgeGeometry, edgeMaterial);
let initialMesh = new THREE.Mesh(tileGeometry, floorMat);    

Object.keys(groundTiles).forEach((key, index) => {
  let tile = groundTiles[key];
  let tileMesh = initialMesh.clone();

  tileMesh.position.set(
    tile.leftPoint[0] + tile.size[0] / 2,
    tile.leftPoint[1] + tile.size[1] / 2,
    0
  );

  tileMesh.scale.x = tile.size[0];
  tileMesh.scale.y = tile.size[1];
  tileMesh.name = `${tile.leftPoint[0]}-${tile.leftPoint[1]}`;

  // Add tile edges (adds tile border lines)
  tileMesh.add(edges.clone());
  scene.add(tileMesh);
});

// add shelving units
const cellGeometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 790, 790, 250 );
const  wireframe = new THREE.WireframeGeometry( cellGeometry );
const cellLine = new THREE.LineSegments(wireframe, shelves_material);

Object.keys(cells).forEach((key, index) => {
  let cell = cells[key];
  const cellMesh = cellLine.clone();
  cellMesh.position.set(
    cell["x"] + 790 / 2,
    // cell["x"],
    cell["y"] + 490 / 2,
    cell["z"] - 250
  );
  scene.add(cellMesh);
});
```

Also, here is a [link](https://ibb.co/fZWOA8) to a screenshot from the final result.

I saw [this](http://blog.sandromartis.com/2016/11/16/merging-geometries/) article regarding merging of geometries, but I don't know how to implement it in my case because of the edges, line segments and wireframe objects I'm using..

Any help would be appriciated

Comment: You can't merge lines with meshes since they are different primitives. I suggest you start to merge you meshes like in the following example: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_minecraft.html

Comment: @Mugen87 Thanks for this. From the example I see he used THREE.BufferGeometryUtils in order to merge plane buffer geometries, which is what I used to draw the tiles, but I can't see how I can combine it with the edges (in order the create sort of a grid..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account @Mugen87's comment, here's a possible approach :

- Pretty straightforward merging of planes
- Using a shader material to draw "borders"

Note : comment out the  `discard;` line to fill the cards with red or whatever material you might want.

[JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Pisha/m3wo19te/)

Comment: Thanks, you example was very helpful. Didn't know shader materials at all